# Trouble using EUSART module on PIC18f87k22

Tags: c, declaration, xc8

i'm trying to configure an UART communication between an arduino pro trinket and my PIC18f87k22.
When running my code i get the following error:

[image: error code]

this is the prototype of the function :

```
char EUSART1_Read(void)
{

RCSTA1bits.SREN = 1;
 while(!PIR1bits.RC1IF)
 {
    ;
 }


if(1 == RCSTA1bits.OERR)
{
    // EUSART1 error - restart

    RCSTA1bits.CREN = 0; 
    RCSTA1bits.CREN = 1; 
}

return RCREG1;
}
```

and this is how i use it (the only use of it so far) :

```
int16_t get_courant()
{
   char courant1;
   char courant2;
   int16_t courant;

   if(EUSART1_is_tx_ready())
           {
               EUSART1_Write(0b00000001);
           }
   if(EUSART1_is_rx_ready())
           {
           courant1= EUSART1_Read(); 
           }

   if(EUSART1_is_tx_ready())
           {
               EUSART1_Write(0b00000010);
           }
   if(EUSART1_is_rx_ready())
           {
           courant2= EUSART1_Read(); 
           }
   if (CheckBit(courant1,8))
           {
           bit_clr(courant1,8);
           courant = (courant1 << 8) | courant2;
           courant = - courant;
           }
   else 
   {
       courant = (courant1 << 8) | courant2;
   }
   return courant;   
   }
```

I tried remplacing the type char with unsigned char or uint8_t, but it changed nothing.
Any ideas on what is wrong with my code?
Ty

Comment: Posting text as text rather than as a picture adds value.  It is searchable and can be copy/pasted.  please edit the error in as text.

Comment: Your error means you have declared the function `EUSART1_Read()` twice. Are you sure that EUSART1_Read is not defined anywhere else, and that you included EUSART1_Read function declaration before calling it in `get_courant()`? Are there any errors in your build? Why don't you past you errors as text, not as image, isn't it simpler?

Comment: Don't think that http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/ but it could be a reason for downvotes you might receive.

Comment: "this is the prototype of the function :" --> code posted is both the function declaration and the definition.   `int16_t get_courant()` needs to see at least the function declaration before using it.  "Any ideas on what is wrong with my code?" --> Post how `int16_t get_courant()` sees the declarations of `char EUSART1_Read(void)`.

Answer (score 0):

Put in one file:

```
// Prototype
char EUSART1_Read(void);
int16_t get_courant(void);

// function definition
char EUSART1_Read(void)
{
    RCSTA1bits.SREN = 1;
    while(!PIR1bits.RC1IF)
    {
        ;
    }
    if (1 == RCSTA1bits.OERR)
    {
        // EUSART1 error - restart
        RCSTA1bits.CREN = 0; 
        RCSTA1bits.CREN = 1; 
    }
    return RCREG1;
}


int16_t get_courant(void)
{
    char courant1;
    char courant2;
    int16_t courant;

    if(EUSART1_is_tx_ready())
    {
        EUSART1_Write(0b00000001);
    }
    if(EUSART1_is_rx_ready())
    {
        courant1= EUSART1_Read(); 
    }

    if(EUSART1_is_tx_ready())
    {
        EUSART1_Write(0b00000010);
    }
    if(EUSART1_is_rx_ready())
    {
        courant2= EUSART1_Read(); 
    }
    if (CheckBit(courant1,8))
    {
        bit_clr(courant1,8);
        courant = (courant1 << 8) | courant2;
        courant = - courant;
     }
     else 
     {
         courant = (courant1 << 8) | courant2;
     }
     return courant;   
}
```